# How to rotate the ball in the direction its moving?I try to use the rotate function but that throws everything off?

Tags: rotation, coordinates, processing

```java
//declaringglobalvaribales

float dia1=50;

//diameteroftheface

float x=400;

float y=400;

float speedX=4;

float speedY=0;

//setup

void setup() {

size(810, 810);
} //draw

void draw() {

background(225);

fill(225, 0, 0);

stroke(0);

ellipse(x, y, dia1, dia1);

fill(0, 225, 0);

//a nose

triangle(x, y, x+10, y+10, x-10, y+10);

//movingtheballXway

x=x+speedX;

//movingtheballYway

y=y+speedY;

//if it hits the left or right corners it will turn around

if (x>width-dia1/2 || x<2+dia1/2) {

    speedX=speedX*-1;
}
// it its hits the top or bottom it will turn around 

if (y>height-dia1/2 || y<2+dia1/2) {

    speedY=speedY*-1;
}

 // this code to move it according to the keys W S D A

void keyPressed() {

if (keyCode=='W') {

    speedX=0;

    speedY=-4;

}
if (keyCode=='S') {

    speedX=0;

    speedY=4;

}
if (keyCode=='A') {

    speedX=-4;

    speedY=0;

}
if (keyCode=='D') {

    speedX=4;

    speedY=0;

}

}
```

I made this ball with a nose, which moves around the screen with the keys W S D A.  If it hits the edges it will bounce back.

I'm trying to change the direction the ball is facing to make it face the same way as it's moving.  I wanted to use rotate for this, but once I use rotate it throws all the coordinates off.  Rotating it back doesn't help either.

I have commented out the stuff I have tried to do.  For example, I tried to translate it to `250,250` and then rotate it afterwards, but then the X and Y coordinates are switched.  Also, the ball won't go all the way to the corners and it moves out (since it's translated down).

What kind of rotation/translation logic do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that using the rotate function on your triangle is wreaking havoc as you are performing the rotate on several variables in your draw loop because you're not telling processing exactly which object you want to transform. One way to do this is to look up the pushMatrix and popMatrix functions (google "processing pushMatrix" to see helpful info for how to use the type and associated functions). It would be cumbersome to implement this into your code as the triangle is created in your draw loop every frame. An easy way to make transformations to a specific shape you have (in your instance, a triangle) is to store it as a PShape and then make transformations as you need to. Since PShape's can easily be transformed using PShape functions you don't need to worry about your transformations effecting other variables (so no need to use push/popmatrix. Here is a commented version of your code that implements your Triangle as a PShape.

```java
//declaringglobalvaribales

float dia1=50;

//diameteroftheface

float x=400;

float y=400;

float speedX=4;

float speedY=0;

//Initialize PShape which we can later store a triangle in
PShape tri;

void setup() {
  size(810, 810);

  //Initialize triangle - this triangle faces right
  tri = createShape(TRIANGLE, 0, 10, 0, -10, 10, 0);
}


void draw() {

  background(225);

  fill(225, 0, 0);

  stroke(0);

  ellipse(x, y, dia1, dia1);

  fill(0, 225, 0);

  //Draw the stored PShape at x and y coordinate
  shape(tri,x,y);

  //movingtheballXway

  x=x+speedX;

  //movingtheballYway

  y=y+speedY;

  //if it hits the left or right corners it will turn around

  if (x>width-dia1/2 || x<2+dia1/2) {
    speedX=speedX*-1;
    //Flip PShape rotation
    tri.rotate(PI);
  } // it its hits the top or bottom it will turn around

  if (y>height-dia1/2 || y<2+dia1/2) {
    speedY=speedY*-1;
    //Flip PShape rotation
    tri.rotate(PI);
  }
}

  // this code to move it according to the keys W S D A

  void keyPressed() {

    if (keyCode=='W') {
      speedX=0;
      speedY=-4;
      //reset triangle orientation (transformation matrix) to original then rotate to face UP
      tri.resetMatrix();
      tri.rotate(-PI/2);
    } 
    if (keyCode=='S') {
      //reset triangle orientation (transformation matrix) to original then rotate to face DOWN
      speedX=0;
      speedY=4;
      tri.resetMatrix();
      tri.rotate(PI/2);
    } 
    if (keyCode=='A') {
      //reset triangle orientation (transformation matrix) to original then rotate to face LEFT
      tri.resetMatrix();
      tri.rotate(PI);
      speedX=-4;
      speedY=0;
    } 
    if (keyCode=='D') {
      //reset triangle orientation (transformation matrix) to original - it is already pointing right
      tri.resetMatrix();
      speedX=4;
      speedY=0;
    }
  }
```

I suspect your next step, or a more efficient way to write this piece of code might be to begin to implement PVectors (google processing PVectors to see helpful info for how to use the type and associated functions) for position and direction of your 'ball'. Here is some commented code that begins to show you how you might implement this in your current code. Although there are many improvements that can be made on this. For more information on how vectors work in processing follow this tutorial - http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/

```java
//declaringglobalvaribales

//diameteroftheface
float dia1=50;

//initialize position PVector and tell it where you want it to be - in this case 400,400
PVector position = new PVector(400, 400);

//how many steps you want your position to move per frame
float speed=4;

//initialize direction vector as 0,0 - the ellipse will not move until you give it a 
//direction as it is initialized with no direction
PVector direction = new PVector(0, 0);

void setup() {
  size(810, 810);
}


void draw() {

  background(225);

  fill(225, 0, 0);

  stroke(0);

  //draw ellipse at your position PVector using the PVectors x and y values
  ellipse(position.x, position.y, dia1, dia1);

  fill(0, 225, 0);

  //drawing a line to indicate what direction the ellipse is heading in using the position coordinates and the position plus direction
  line(position.x, position.y, position.x+direction.x*4, position.y+direction.y*4);

  // add the direction to the position to make it move
  position =position.add(direction);

  //if the position PVector is close to sketch edges invert its direction by multiplying direction PVector by -1
  if (position.x>width-dia1/2 || position.x<2+dia1/2) {
    direction.mult(-1);
  }

  if (position.y>height-dia1/2 || position.y<2+dia1/2) {
    direction.mult(-1);
  }
}

// this code to move it according to the keys W S D A

void keyPressed() {
  //set the direction coordinates based on keypresses
  //also multiply the direction by speed variable so it moves at a speed set at top of script
  if (keyCode=='W') {
    direction.y = -1*speed;
    direction.x = 0;
  } 
  if (keyCode=='S') {
    direction.y = 1*speed;
    direction.x = 0;
  } 
  if (keyCode=='A') {
    direction.x = -1*speed;
    direction.y = 0;
  } 
  if (keyCode=='D') {
    direction.x = 1*speed;
    direction.y = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a center point, an angle you want to face, and a distance from that center, you can use `cos()` and `sin()` to calculate the end point. Here's a simple example:

```java
float angle = 0;
float distance = 25;

void draw(){
  angle += .01;

  float startX = width/2;
  float startY = height/2;

  float endX = startX + cos(angle)*distance;
  float endY = startY + sin(angle)*distance;

  background(255);
  line(startX, startY, endX, endY);
}
```

In the future, please try to narrow your question down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this before posting.